# copy-in-copy-out parameter(value-result parameter passing)

Tags: parameter-passing, ada

what will be the result of the following C-like program, if the parameter passing mechanism is copy-in-copy-out, like in out in Ada?
During the execution of `swap(v, list[v])`, `v` will be updated to 3. When copying out, will the result of the second parameter copied to `list[3]`, or `list[1]`?

```ada
swap(int x, int y){
    int t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
}

main(){
    v = 1;
    int list[5] = {1,3,5,7,9};
    swap(v, list[v]);
    print v, list[0...4];
}
```

Comment: As this is homework, is there a reason you havent written an Ada program to find out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ada's parameter passing mechanisim is *not* copy-in-copy out**. Ada is not like C, where the mechanisim is explicit and the compiler will follow it even if it would be stupid to do so.

There are some specific situations where the language specifies that things are passed by reference. Otherwise, it is actually up to the compiler and you are not allowed to rely on one mechanism being used rather than another. In practice, **compilers will do the sensible thing**, which usually boils down to copy if the object fits in a machine register, and reference otherwise.

What happens in an Ada version of the C code you listed depends on exactly how you translate it to Ada. I suspect what you will find when you do so is that things that would have caused potentially suprising behavior in C, the Ada compiler either won't let you do, or it will force you to document in such a way that it no longer looks wierd.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters are bound before the call is executed, so x is bound to v and y is bound to list[1].